# Why won't the "on_messages" function run in my discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

The function that won't run when testing it out on discord is `on_messages`. The rest works and runs fine! I thought maybe it's because I'm not calling the function, but I'm not really calling it in the last function, `on_message`, either, "you rang?" - that works fine.

Compare the first function with the last, what am I doing differently there, that the last one runs but not the first?

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
sad_words = ["sad", "depressed", "unhappy", "cba", "angry"]
starter_encouragements = ["misery is the only thing I know", "as my father said: learn to embrace the darkness in life",
                          "grow up, you're an addams", "I like being miserable",
                          "dark and gloomy is the only way to be"]

@client.event
async def on_messages(message):
    if message.content.startswith('goodnight'):
        await message.channel.send("Goodnight")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Lurch is ready, master")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    if message.content.startswith('lurch'):
        await message.channel.send('You rang?')
    else:
        if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
            await message.channel.send(random.choice(starter_encouragements))


client.run("MY_HIDDEN_TOKEN", bot=True)
```

Comment: question. Why do you have **two** on messages?

Comment: @BuddyBob What do you mean by that?

Comment: @BuddyBob Hi, do you mean why do I have two functions instead of it all being in one?

Comment: in the code I see you have **2** `async def on_message(message):` functions. Is that not redundant. Why not combine them?

Comment: Hi I'm really silly (noob programmer) lol, I tried nesting another if statement before but for some reason thought it was illegal, turns out the syntax was just wrong in terms of indenting. I've done it and it works now, thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

`on_message` is one of the event handlers you can define for a bot. It is called when a message is received.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference lists no event for which an `on_messages` function will be called.

Comment: AHHHH!  That makes so much sense thank you. So that's why it isn't working. Then, would I be able to make another function for it under on_message ? I thought it was just a function name tbqh lol thus I thought I could name it anything I wanted to other than on_message